# Change the style of scrollbar on click/holding it using webkit css similar to gmail chat

Tags: jquery, css, webkit

Hello i am trying to modify the webkit properties of the scrollbar whenever user uses mouse to scroll the scrollbar similar to what is happening in gmail chat ..

Till now i have succeeded in modifying the properties on hover as:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { 
    background-color: hsl(216, 8%, 70%);
}
```

How to modify it on scroll event? Thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:active` state:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active { 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.. (was trying to do it with jquery ... huh .. hell lot of events i wrote ... so simple with css)